# Datepicker shortcuts e.g 1m, 1y, 1d

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a datepicker that support entering by the user 5y and it will return now + 5years.
if possible if prefer to use jquery ui datepicker control, or if someone know about other control.

The jquery control blocks entering non numeric characters.

Thanks, Pini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the demo from [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Any+Time](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) is my go-to date (and time) picker. Highly customizable.